# How do I assign two values to an option tag in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

For example how would I display two images using this:

```
<option value="dog.png">Dog</option>
```

Would it be like

```
<option value="dog.png"; "dog2.png">Dog</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
<option value="dog.png;dog2.png">Dog</option>
```

Of course you will need to parse the value before you can use it. Have a look at the [split method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).